# In intellij idea, how to pick up suggested item in intelligent suggestion list without using arrow key?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

We know that Intellij idea has powerful intelligent suggestions.

Here while coding, I get below suggestions.
[image]

Now if I want to pick the third item, I have move my right hand away to the right corner of the keyboard, then use the down arrow key to select the third item.

Is there any way to pick up this item without moving my hand? Can I use other key shortcuts instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any way how to make the SmartComplete selection easier than using the arrow keys.

You can add an additional keyboard shortcut to the `Down` and `Up` editor action in intellij ideas keymap setting. 
You can use the `find action by shortcut` feature in order to pick the right one.

This should solve you problem.

**Caution - Opinionated!**

Ten years ago my writs start to hurt, because I was hacking on a german keyboard layout - curly braces are really difficult to type on that layout.

Therefore, I decided to change the keyboard and keyboard layout. 
Most hacking friendly keyboards have arrows next to your right hand or they provide an easy way to use an overlay.
Since than, I use the TypeMatrix Keyboard and the colemak layout. Everything is nearby and I never had problems with my wrists again.

I would suggest, that you change your keyboard and/or layout if you want to improve your typing workflow and reduce the likelihood of getting muscle strain.

When your neck, elbow and writs start to hurt, you know what I am talking about ;-)

Comment: get it. Thanks for your story;)